# change url while scrolling with hash

Tags: javascript, url, scroll

Does anyone know how to change the URL while scrolling? 
I have this:

```
$(document).on('scroll',function(e)
 {
$('section').each(function()
{
    if ( $(this).offset().top < window.pageYOffset + 10 
    &&   $(this).offset().top + 
         $(this).height() > window.pageYOffset + 10
       ) 
    {
     var data = window.location.hash;
     window.location.hash = hash;
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the url (not only the hash) without reloading the browser see [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) and search for pushState. Changing the [hash value](http://lea.verou.me/2011/05/change-url-hash-without-page-jump/) of your current URL is also possible with pushState.

Comment: how can i add that to my script?

Comment: How about history.pushState(null, null, hash); Everything is described in the provided links.